# How to deploy hangfire with .net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, hangfire

as many webapp does we are using multi-layer structure in our application. We got
this layers

[image]

And all of my code for hangfire in CronJob project.

inside the Cronjob/homecontroller

```
 public IActionResult Index()
        {

RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate('1', () => CheckFail(), Cron.Daily);
```

It works for once then work repeatly.

The question is we are deploying only WebUI project to server. How to confgiure with it. Cronjob uses the other layers